# Insert using multiple SELECTs with where clause

Tags: mysql

Below SQL gives an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (customerid, 'customeremail', 'customerphone', restaurantid, 'restaurantem' at line 1

```
INSERT into Order (customerid, 'customeremail', 'customerphone', restaurantid, 'restaurantemail', 'restaurantphone', dishid, 'dishname', price, timestamp, 'deliverystatus', qualityratings, deliveryratings, 'dishcomments') values 
 Select Cus.idCustomer, Cus.email, Cus.cell, Src.idSource, Src.email, Src.telephone, Dis.idDish, Dis.description, Dis.price, current_timestamp, 5, 5, 'Comments'
  From (Select idCustomer, email, cell, row_number() Over(order by (1)) as RowNum From Customer WHERE email='A.B@gmail.com') Cus
   Join (Select idSource, email, telephone, row_number() Over(order by (1)) as RowNum From FROM Source WHERE idSource = '1') Src
    ON Cus.RowNum = Src.RowNum
   Join (Select idDish, description, price, row_number() Over(order by (1)) as RowNum From Dish WHERE  idDish = '3') Dis
    ON Src.RowNum = Dis.RowNum
```

Comment: Order is a reserved word use backtick for it. And get rid of single quotes on field names.

Comment: Abhik - Adding back tick did not help.

Comment: You also need to remove the single quotes from the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Order is your Table Name ? I don't think it's a smart choice... It's a reserved word in SQL (Order By...)

@Abhik Chakraborty suggested you backtick it. I think you should change the name to Orders to avoid confusion.

Comment: & @ Abhik - I did what you suggested. No luck still